# My PLE Counter value is 483.what is the safe side for PLE buffer manager value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-tuning

Today morning i ran this scripts and i got 483.is that counter value is good ?

```
select [OBJECT_NAME],
[counter_name],
[cntr_value]from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where[OBJECT_NAME]like '%Manager%'
AND [counter_name]='page life expectancy'
```

Comment: What is max server memory and total RAM present on system? Anyways this does not looks good

Comment: SELECT
(physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB,
(locked_page_allocations_kb/1024) AS Locked_pages_used_Sqlserver_MB,
(total_virtual_address_space_kb/1024) AS Total_VAS_in_MB,
process_physical_memory_low,
process_virtual_memory_low
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;i Ran this Scripts and it gives me memory used by sqlserver 8978MB.how do i fix this problem?@Shanky

Comment: Is the server running fine? If it is this might be normal for you.

Comment: pretty much i do not find any problem so far .Can you please tell me if PLE running high what kind of problems i could get ?@Sean Gallardy

Comment: I asked you max server memory and you gave me memory consumed by SQL Server. Anyways I *assume* max server memory is around 9 G in that case 483 seems bit less BUT, PLE fluctuating on SQL Server is quite normal and this can happen many a times when load on system is high. Other question does PLE remains to this value always or it rises up ?

Comment: yeah you are right Maximum server memory is 9 G .as usual it stays under sometimes low in our production .today i found PLE counter value 483.@Shanky

Comment: So if it always remains low you might be facing memory crunch, it would be better to add more RAM and increase max server memory value.

Comment: To add to @Shanky who has already given great advice, it's a good idea to log PLE counters and average them out to see what is normal for your environment so you can tell when you have a spike. sp_whoisactive is a free script you can run that tells you queries that use a lot of memory / cpu and make indicate who is hurting the PLE. But more ram is always good.

Comment: Monitor the value over busy times and quiet times and see how it fluctuates. Then look at indexing.

Comment: quite times i got PLE 106 and busy time 483@RandolphWest

Answer (score 2):

The Page Life Expectancy counter tells you for how many seconds an 8KB data page will remain in the buffer pool, before being flushed out.

A low number can be a sign of memory pressure, but it may also be a sign of nothing.

If your data access patterns involve a lot of report-style queries, reading a lot of data from large tables, this could be normal.

Monitor the value over several days, at different times in the day, and you may find that this is an outlier. I have a customer whose PLE goes to zero every time a certain large index is rebuilt, but it steadily increases after that.

My first sense is to review indexes, and see if a well-placed index can help with large reads. Another best practice is to avoid using `SELECT * FROM table` if you can help it.

You may need to increase the physical RAM in the server, but that shouldn't be your first reaction.

*(Read more here about PLE and NUMA nodes: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/page-life-expectancy-isnt-what-you-think/)*

Comment: today morning My PLE was super low and i found agent job was running since 3 hours and taking most of memory .after agent job done i count PLE value is 387 .why PLE runs high sometimes?@Randolph West

Comment: Was the Agent Job related to index rebuilds? That will definitely do it. That's also expected behaviour, so once the job is done, and the PLE number climbs again, you're fine.